# Attacking a permanent image

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, traps, illusion

If a player attacks a **permanent image** set in place as a trap to stall enemies I am assuming the image has an AC of 10+size mod as per the spell **major image**.

If the player succeeds on their attack would the character immediately disbelieve the image?

Or

Would the image move to make them believe that they missed but allow a will save to disbelieve?

For reference:

**Permanent image reads:**

> This spell functions like silent image, except that the figment includes visual, auditory, olfactory, and thermal elements, and the spell is permanent. By concentrating, you can move the image within the limits of the range, but it is static while you are not concentrating.

**Silent image reads:**

> This spell creates the visual illusion of an object, creature, or force, as visualized by you. The illusion does not create sound, smell, texture, or temperature. You can move the image within the limits of the size of the effect.

**Major image reads:**

> This spell functions like silent image, except that sound, smell, and thermal illusions are included in the spell effect. While concentrating, you can move the image within the range.
>
> The image disappears when struck by an opponent unless you cause the illusion to react appropriately.

**The figment subschool reads:**

> A figment’s AC is equal to 10 + its size modifier.

Comment: Just so you know, you can declare to the site that text is a blockquote by putting a single `>` at the start of that paragraph. (Italics aren't recognised as quotes by the site or by accessible browsers, so we don't use them in answer or question posts to show that something is a quote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Permanent Image's  description says:

> but it is static while you are not concentrating.

The image would be seen as a man just standing there waiting for the hit which would be helpless image rather than a major image assuming you aren't controlling it directly. Helpless reads:

> A helpless character is paralyzed, held, bound, sleeping, unconscious, or otherwise completely at an opponent’s mercy. A helpless target is treated as having a Dexterity of 0 (–5 modifier). Melee attacks against a helpless target get a +4 bonus (equivalent to attacking a prone target). Ranged attacks gets no special bonus against helpless targets

All of these added together the image would have 5 armor due to the negative dextery modifier and melee attacks would get +4 to hitting it since it is helpless.

Considering the Major Image says:

> The image disappears when struck by an opponent unless you cause the illusion to react appropriately.

Both of the options you have given are incorrect. As a melee attacker will not miss as long as he doesn't crit fail the image will disappear the moment an attack is attempted unless you want to have players roll a 1d20 to see if they will crit fail.